# sed replace matching line which does not start with #

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have one file named "test-file". It has just two following lines (one line with # sign in the front and second line with same content but without hash):

```
#contents of line
contents of line
```

I want to update/replace the contents of second line by using sed command. I know its simple syntax for example:

```
sed -i 's/.*contents of line.*/updated contents/' test-file
```

but the above command is replacing both of the lines whereas I don't want to update the first line with # sign in the front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
sed 's/^[^#]*contents of line.*/updated contents/' test-file
```

or with the start of line anchor `^`, and you know that line start with `content ...`, you could do:

```
sed 's/^contents of line.*/updated contents/' test-file
```

If you know which line you are going to update, you can change directly with its address line number like.

```
sed '2s/.*/updated content/' test-file
```

add `-i` when you were happy with the result.

Answer (score 8):

You could do the edit the following way:

```
sed -e '/^#/!s/.*/UPDATED_CONTENTS/' input-file.txt
```

or

```
sed -e '/^#/!c\
UPDATED_CONTENTS' input-file.txt
```

this is to read as: for any line that does not begin with a `#` , change that whole line to what is specified.

And in case you are concerned that the octothorpe can be preceded by blanks, then tweak the regex to `/^[[:blank:]]*#/` while keeping the rest exactly as is.